# Magento 2 get admin url

Tags: magento2, admin, url

We are already know that How to get Admin page url in magento1 from this question [How to get Admin page url?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/how-to-get-admin-page-url/10245)

But how to get it at magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to get admin URL to Magento 2 then your can try below Solution

In order to get admin  URL ,you need to inject the  `Magento_Backend ‘s` helper class `Magento\Backend\Helper\Data`  to  **__construct()** function.

```
/**
 * @var Magento\Backend\Helper\Data
 */
protected $HelperBackend;

public function __construct(
.....
\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $HelperBackend
....
) {
$this->HelperBackend = $HelperBackend;
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function getAdminUrl()
{
echo $this->HelperBackend->getHomePageUrl();
}
```

Comment: In their latest release, i.e, Magento 2.2.0, I've noticed that they have deprecated the `\Magento\Backend\Helper\Data` class. So I'm assuming there's another way to do it?